# How to GET Data from Elasticsearch with a specific time range

Tags: c#, rest, elasticsearch, asp.net-core

I have dates at my **elasticsearch** which include a field **Timestamp** from type date.
Now I will filter results only **between two dates**. I'm using **Nest** and **C#**.

**How can I get results where the Timestamp is between 1th of mai 2019, 10:00:00 and 5th of mai 2019, 23:59:59?**

Right now my search request looks like that:

```
                result = ElasticClient.Search<_doc>
                (document => document
                    .Source(src => src
                        .Includes(i => i
                            .Fields(
                            p => p.Timestamp,
                            p => p.Value
                            )
                        )
                    )
                    .Query(q => q
                        .Match(m => m
                            .Field(f => f.DataRecordId)
                            .Query(search)
                        )   
                    )
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [range query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) for this. Assuming that the format used for date field is `YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` and field name is `timestamp`, the following query will work:

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "timestamp": {
        "gte": "2019-05-01 10:00:00",
        "lte": "2019-05-05 23:59:59"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @FrankMehlhop you can easily do that by looking at the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/date-range-query-usage.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter data in this range, try this :

```
            var result = ElasticClient.Search<_doc>
            (document => document
                .Source(src => src
                    .Includes(i => i
                        .Fields(
                        p => p.Timestamp,
                        p => p.Value
                        )
                    )
                )
                .Query(q => q
                    .Bool(b => b
                        .Must(m => m
                            .DateRange(r => r
                                .Field(p => p.Timestamp)
                                .GreaterThanOrEquals("2019-05-01T10:00:00")
                                .LessThanOrEquals("2019-05-05T23:59:59")
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
```

[Date Range Query Usage](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/numeric-range-query-usage.html)

Comment: It looks good but it does *not work* in my case. I also find it at some documentations. Did you you tried it out?

Comment: can you provide more details why it does not work in your case ?